# Trying to target .current-page-item in wordpress, can target style

Tags: css, wordpress

I want the navigation item corresponding to the page the user is on to change color when the page is active.  I can't seem to target the items correctly though.

Link:  http://www.cicadabooks.co.uk/new/distribution/

Style : `.main-nav ul.main-nav li a, #widget li a.current-page-item {color:#F06;}`

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

```
#menu-main li.current_page_item a {color: #F06 !important;}
```

Comment: Really? Try adding !important to it; it looks like your other color styles on it are !important.

Comment: I changed it to have !important. I looked at the site again and it looked like that was indeed the problem.

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer. ;) (Not to nag, I just figured since you're new you might not know to do that.)

Comment: By the way, neXib makes a good point; it's better to solve this by removing !important from all the other places than adding it here. Also, I noticed you have two id="widget" elements, which isn't allowed (id is supposed to be unique).

Comment: This is great, thank you! I've been trying to find a simplistic solution for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
#widget li.current_page_item a {color: #F06;}
```

Comment: That won't work because that would match something like this: <div id="widget"><li><anything class="current_page_item><a ...>

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
.main-nav ul.main-nav li.current_page_item a, #widget li.current_page_item a {color: #f06; }
```

The reason being, with your code, you are saying that the Class is assigned to the link (a), but with wordpress, the current-page-item class is assigned to the li tag.

Comment: Thanks Tom, but with your code targeting the li doesn't work either.  I understand what you are saying, I'm just not sure why either solution does not work.

Comment: Crimson above noted that it needed to include !important.  That did the trick, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use important unless you HAVE TO.

This will solve it:

```
#sidebar .menu-main-container ul.menu li.current_page_item a{ color: #F06;}
```

**Edit:**
The reason this works is that part of the inherited style also specifies ul, so to override it you need to be just as specific (or more specific).

Answer (score 0):

You have your code a bit backwards.
Essentially all you need to target is this:

```
li.current_page_item a
```

If you have more than one navigation, just bubble up to the container of the nav for more control.